# Accessing bootstrap CSS within meteor?

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experimenting with a few different UI libraries for React/Meteor. I'd like to eventually move towards Bootstrap 4 and CSS Modules but as a stepping stone I'm trying to get familiar with Bootstrap 3. I have installed from meteor with 'meteor add tabs:bootstrap'.

https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap

However none of the styling seems to be activated. I guess that I need to import the CSS files individually into each component/file? How do I import Bootstrap styles into my meteor project after installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meteor add twbs:bootstrap` should be sufficient to get going. Its CSS is bundled together before shipped to clients.

`npm install boostrap` is recommended forward if your Meteor version supports installing packages from NPM. Take a look at this [thread](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20389) for a reason. If you are on this path, remember to `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` somewhere top on structure, i.e., where you hook React to your application.

Comment: Thanks Season, I was able to get it working using just the meteor add twbs:bootstrap  command. Thanks for the link, going forward I will migrate to the NPM version.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Inside the head of the first client html page. You could load bootstrap css and js file, either locally or from cdn.

```
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



[![<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>][1]][1]
```

Comment: This works, but ideally I would use a Meteor specific solution? All my other dependencies are installable via NPM or atmosphere. Is there a similar method for bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, could you explain the "locally" part?  I'm having trouble getting bootstrap CSS from NPM to load before my app's bundled CSS.  Even when using `<meteor-bundled-css>`.  The only way is to put a CDN link above `<meteor-bundled-css>`.